# Having trouble aligning items with css

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to recreate the design as seen below.

[image]

What is the best way to recreate this without using a bunch of javascript and absolute alignment.

Comment: I'd say flexbox or grid, but this question is opinion based.

Comment: @RamondeVries Yes that's what i thought. but i do not know way the rows can be overflowing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do a masonry layout. Maybe this article from css-tricks can help you :
https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout

To sum it up, there is several solutions : pure css, css + javascript and libraries